# Problem with replacing a comma with a period

Tags: r, dataframe

I replace the comma with a period in the data.frame column

```
data[,22] <- as.numeric(sub(",", ".", sub(".", "", data[,22], fixed=TRUE), fixed=TRUE))
```

But I have values that look like this: 110.00, 120.00, 130.00...

When replacing, I get the value:11000.0, 12000.0, 13000.0

And I would like to get: 110.0,120.0, 130.0....

My column 22 data.frame:

```
|    n   |
|--------|
|   92,5 |
|   94,5 |
|   96,5 |
|  110.00|
|  120.00|
|  130.00|
```

What I want to get:

```
|    n   |
|--------|
|   92.5 |
|   94.5 |
|   96.5 |
|  110.0|
|  120.0|
|  130.0|
```

or

```
|    n   |
|--------|
|   92.5 |
|   94.5 |
|   96.5 |
|  110.00|
|  120.00|
|  130.00|
```

Comment: What's the class of your column `class(data[,22])`? Can you share of values from the column?

Comment: "numeric"  before that, there was "character"

Comment: c(11000,12000,13000,1205014050)

Comment: you can apply modulo operation onto what you got to achieve your wish

Comment: and do not tell me how to present the module?

Comment: Please add to your question the original values **and** what your expected output should look like.

Comment: @LMc updated description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't replace the periods since they are already in the format that you want. Replace only commas to period and turn the data to numeric.

```
data[[22]] <- as.numeric(sub(',', '.', fixed = TRUE, data[[22]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
data[[22]] <- as.numeric(str_replace(data[[2]], ",", fixed(".")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gsub` like below

```
transform(
  df,
  n = as.numeric(gsub("\\D", ".", n))
)
```

where non-digital character, i.e., "," or ".", are replaced by "."